# can we use PRIORVALUE function for text area in validation rule

Tags: validation, validation-rule

can we use `PRIORVALUE` function for text area in validation rule

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

Please refer to the [guide](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&type=5) for more information.

Also, next time, please add some details to your question like what have you tried, where you are stuck etc.